# Quick Book Error You and sam working on this at the same time

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

I am trying to update the data in quick book while updating i am getting exception as follows

"***You and sam were working on this at the same time. sam finished before you did, so your work was not saved.***" I have attached the screenshot for your reference. Please let me know if you need any detailed explanation about this issue. Any help would be appreciated.

**Code**

```
  oBillHeader.VendorId = new IdType() { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = vendorID };
  oBillHeader.VendorName = vendorNameVal;
  oBill.Header = oBillHeader;
  oBill.Line = oBillLineList.ToArray();
  oBill.Id = new IdType { idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, Value = Convert.ToString(ViewState["ReponseBillId"]) };
  oBill.SyncToken = "2";
  var oNewBill = service.Update(oBill);
```

**Image:**

[image]

Comment: Hint: The stack trace still shows the name you tried to edit out.

Comment: This question can't be answered, because the answer lies within your code.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth it shows my name i just edited using paint

Comment: @DanielHilgarth i just signout the quickbook website and then i tried updating at that time also i am getting exception

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the latest sync token of the object and use the same in the update query.

Relevant docs on SyncToken values:

- https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/0200_key_concepts

Thanks

Comment: Where to get the latest sync token

Comment: You can read the object using getByID api. In the response XML, you'll get the sync token.
V2 QBD ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0500_quickbooks_windows/0600_object_reference/bill ( plz check the 'SyncToken' attribute ).

Comment: while updating it's asking for sync token here i am giving it manually

Comment: while creating bill iam getting sync token as 1 i need to update the bill so for that i need to pass the sync token as 1 is that correct

Comment: After creation, you should get sync token as 0.So, in the first update query, you need to use sync token as 0.
You can try it using ApiExplorer tool. 

ApiExplorer - https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V2QBO#Bill

QBO Bill docs - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0050_data_services/v2/0400_quickbooks_online/bill ( sample create and update XMLs are available in the docs)