# How can I Update Customer using Id, SyncToken for QBO IPP .NET SDK V3?

Tags: c#, intuit-partner-platform, quickbooks-online

How can I Update Customer using Id, SyncToken for QBO IPP .NET SDK V3?

Getting an errror (You and admin@gmail.com were working on this at the same time. ajoshi@varstreet.com finished before you did, so your work was not saved.)

Please suggest me where i am going wrong.

```
                IdType CustID = new IdType();
                CustID.Value = "22";

                var NewqboCustomer = new Customer()
                {


                    Id = CustID,
                    SyncToken = "0",

                    // Display name as Customer Name
                    Name = "Name",
                    ShowAs = "Name", //Print on check 

                    //                                

                    //Contact Info 
                    Title = "",
                    GivenName = "Contact1",
                    MiddleName = "",
                    FamilyName = "Contact1",
                    //   

                    //Notes ="Notes ",


                    Notes = new Note[]
                            {
                                new Note()
                                {                                        
                                    Content ="Test Notes",

                                }

                            },

                    TypeOf = partyType.Organization,

                    Address = new PhysicalAddress[]
                            {
                                new PhysicalAddress()
                                    {
                                        Line1 = "bill Line 1",
                                        Line2 = "Bill Line 2",
                                        Line3 =  "Bill Line 3",
                                        Line4 =  "Bill Line 4",
                                        Line5 =  "Bill Line 5",
                                        City = " Bill City ",
                                        Country ="Bill Country",
                                        CountyCode ="Bill Counrty code",
                                        CountrySubDivisionCode = "NC",
                                        PostalCode = "55712",
                                        PostalCodeSuffix="Postal Code Suffix",
                                        Tag = new string[]{"Billing"}
                                    },

                                     new PhysicalAddress()
                                    {
                                        Line1 = "Ship Line 11",
                                        Line2 = "Ship Line 21",
                                        Line3 =  "Ship Line 3",
                                        Line4 =  "Ship Line 4",
                                        Line5 =  "Ship Line 5",
                                        City =    "Ship City ",
                                        Country ="Ship Country",
                                        CountyCode ="Ship Counrty code",
                                        CountrySubDivisionCode = "NC",
                                        PostalCode = "55712",
                                        PostalCodeSuffix="Shippf",
                                        Tag = new string[]{"Shipping"}
                                    }                                       


                            },

                    Phone = new TelephoneNumber[]
                            {
                                new TelephoneNumber()
                                {
                                    DeviceType = "Work",
                                    FreeFormNumber = "111-345-3456"
                                },
                                new TelephoneNumber()
                                {
                                    DeviceType = "Mobile",
                                    FreeFormNumber = "111-345-3457"
                                },
                                new TelephoneNumber()
                                {
                                    DeviceType = "Fax",
                                    FreeFormNumber = "111-345-3457"
                                }
                            },

                    WebSite = new WebSiteAddress[]
                            {
                                new WebSiteAddress()
                                {
                                    URI = "http://www.varstreet.com"
                                }
                            },

                    Email = new EmailAddress[]
                            {
                                new EmailAddress()
                                {
                                    Address = "india@varstreet.com"
                                }
                            },

                    SalesTermId = new IdType()
                    {
                        //idDomain = idDomainEnum.QBO, 
                        //Value = "8" 
                    },


                };

                var output = commonService.Update(NewqboCustomer);
```

Answer (score 2):

Before making any update on any object, you should query that object using findById call to get the latest syncToken. Please use the latest sync token in the next update call.
It will resolve this issue.

GetById Ref - https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0055_devkits/0150_ipp_.net_devkit_3.0/0002_synchronous_calls/0001_data_service_apis#FindById()_Method

Similar issue Ref - [Quick Book Error You and sam working on this at the same time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19403963/quick-book-error-you-and-sam-working-on-this-at-the-same-time/19404283#19404283)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Unless you do a read just before you update, the metadata is stale/not the latest.
So, if you try to update on this, then you get the error for the conflicting metadata related to the object.
Once, you do the read and your object has the latest metadata, you can then update the object successfully.
The syncToken may/maynot change but metadata does. So, it needs to be refreshed before any update along with the sync token.

```
<MetaData>
<CreateTime>2013-04-23T18:10:52-07:00</CreateTime>
<LastUpdatedTime>2013-04-23T18:10:52-07:00</LastUpdatedTime>
</MetaData>
```

Comment: I had an easier time by doing a sparse update (sparse=true), which does not need the metadata at all. Also, I mistakenly thought I was supposed to increment the SyncToken when sending it back, rather than just passing it back as received from the read request.